# React: Router Process Issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs

There is the sample code that I've failed making stable route and getting " MIME type ('text/html') is not executable " error :

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

class App extends Component {
  render (){
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="app">
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={ComponentFirst} />
            <Route path='/element/:id' component={ComponentSecond} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

**.webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  entry: ['@babel/polyfill', './src/index.js'],
  output: {
    filename: 'main.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
  performance: {
    hints: false
  },
  devServer : {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname,"dist"),
    compress: true,
    open: true,
    historyApiFallback: true
  }
 }
```

*When I run the app I'm getting exact path without an issue. However, when I try to getting '/element/:id' path, getting the ' MIME type ' issue from above the code. Is that code setup missing something or might be add some another feature into webpack ?*

Comment: Could you try adding `exact` to your `/element/:id` route?

Comment: @AndrewSteinheiser not showing the path and getting 'ERR_ABORTED 404' error.

Comment: I'm not sure about your use case, but if you don't need to eject your app and config your webpack manually, you could just use `create-react-app` and let them maintain your webpack configs. They are constantly updating and patching, so to maintain a webpack going forward can be a daunting task.

Answer (score 0):

did you try removing BrowserRouter tag? documentation says that you can do that just under the Switch

Comment: I fixed it to re-assign some dummy code. Thanks for all answers and contributions.